# Accessing SSRS server report from local application

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have deployed my SSRS reports in the server. Is it possible for me to access that report from my local web application. I have given the server's credentials in the web.config. But still its not displaying the report and it shows some error like `Cannot create a connection to data source 'DataSource1'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)`.

When I hosted the same application in the server it is working absolutely fine.

Can anyone tell me why am not able to access the reports from my local system?

Answer (score 1):

This is not my code, but ideally is all you have to do. I remember using it successfully in one of previous projects some time back

```
private void ShowReport()
{
    try
    {
        string urlReportServer = "http://sqlDBServer//Reportserver";
        rptViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote; // ProcessingMode will be Either Remote or Local
        rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(urlReportServer); //Set the ReportServer Url
        rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/ReportName"; //Passing the Report Path                

        //Creating an ArrayList for combine the Parameters which will be passed into SSRS Report
        ArrayList reportParam = new ArrayList();
        reportParam = ReportDefaultPatam();

        ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[reportParam.Count];
        for (int k = 0; k < reportParam.Count; k++)
        {
            param[k] = (ReportParameter)reportParam[k];
        }
        // pass crendentitilas
        //rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = 
        //  new ReportServerCredentials("uName", "PassWORD", "doMain");

        //pass parmeters to report
        rptViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(param); //Set Report Parameters
        rptViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Ref: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/675762/Call-SSRS-Reports-by-using-Csharp